# Get video usage duration in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm tracking the html5 video for duration. If a play a video and pause at 2 sec, i get a usage duration for 2 sec in console. Again if i'm resume the video at 2 sec and play for next 3 secs. I get usage duration of 5 secs instead of 3 secs.
This is my code.

```
time: function(video) {
  var seconds = 0;
  video = $("#" + video.id()).find("video").get(0);
  if (video.played.length > 0) {
    seconds += video.played.end(0) - video.played.start(0);         
  }
  return Math.round(seconds);
}
```

I'm trying to get latest start time on every resume. and subtract that from video played end. But video.played.start value is always zero. instead of retrieving the new start time on resume.

Can anyone help around this

Comment: i guess `video.played.start(0)` is always the 0 start point of the video. isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, But how can take latest start date instead of initial time which will always be zero

Comment: Works as designed. `.played` implements the `TimeRanges` interface, and for that it is explicitly _specified_, _“the ranges in such an object are ordered, don't overlap, and don't touch (**adjacent ranges are folded into one bigger range**)”_ So if you play your video from 0s to 2s, and then from 2s to 5s, the browser _must_ combine those into one range from 0s to 5s. Only if there was a gap in between, say after pausing at 2s you moved the time cursor to 3s, and then played it from there to 5s again, you would get _two_ ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You could measure the time between the user clicks play and later then clicks stop or pause.